# Выделить button при нажатом tabPage c#

Tags: c#, winforms, tab

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на вкладку tabPage выделялась нужная кнопка button. Спасибо. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Метод `Focus` вызовите

Comment: Здесь два вопроса в одном: 1) как делать что-либо при переходе на вкладку? 2) как выделить кнопку (уточните что именно имеется ввиду: фокус, цвет или что-то другое)? Предлагаю сконцентрироваться на одном.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно подписаться на событие `SelectedIndexChanged`:

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (tabControl1.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            button2.BackColor = button3.BackColor = button4.BackColor = Color.Empty;
            break;
        case 1:
            button2.BackColor = Color.Red;
            button1.BackColor = button3.BackColor = button4.BackColor = Color.Empty;
            break;
        case 2:
            button3.BackColor = Color.Red;
            button1.BackColor = button2.BackColor = button4.BackColor = Color.Empty;
            break;
        case 3:
            button4.BackColor = Color.Red;
            button1.BackColor = button2.BackColor = button3.BackColor = Color.Empty;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь в данном вопросе.